# NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification not fired on either iOS device

Tags: core-data, icloud, nspersistentstore

I have set up core data to work with iCloud using SQLite logs, I have both the Core Data and SQLite logs turned on and to level 3 in my schema, none of which produce errors on getting or putting data from either my local store or cloud store.

My local store stores all SQLite data, while the cloud store is configured to only move around 2 entities, as all of the local ones never need updating.

When logging the persistent stores, they both appear.

on developer.icloud.com, the folder exists to store data, with two subfolders (one for iPad and other for iPhone). In each of these folders are two subfolders and a `receipt.0.cdt` file.

Even though everything seems to be setup, when I manipulate one of the two entities within my application, `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` is never fired (on either device).

Even though the local data store (which holds a local copy of all entities) is updated and this change is reflected in the UI.

Here are the stores being manipulated (logged while manipulation happens)

```
2013-03-03 22:02:49.826 Clueless[1168:907] MOC P-Stores: (
        "<NSSQLCore: 0x1d5b1180> (URL: file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/<id~com~company~appname>/Data.nosync/CategoryModel.sqlite)",
        "<NSSQLCore: 0x1d5ca280> (URL: file://localhost/var/mobile/Applications/EEBE0D5E-1AC0-4A11-AA4B-FB9A63A7F95A/Documents/CategoryModel.sqlite)"
    )
```

Below is a log of the data produced after I manipulate an entity:

```
2013-03-03 22:02:49.836 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
2013-03-03 22:02:49.839 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZIMAGEANSWERAVAILABILITY SET Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2013-03-03 22:02:49.842 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2013-03-03 22:02:49.844 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)18
2013-03-03 22:02:49.845 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)1
2013-03-03 22:02:49.851 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZIMAGEANSWERAVAILABILITY SET Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2013-03-03 22:02:49.861 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)2
2013-03-03 22:02:49.863 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)13
2013-03-03 22:02:49.865 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)1
2013-03-03 22:02:49.866 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: UPDATE ZSYMBOL SET ZANSWERSTATE = ?, Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND Z_OPT = ?
2013-03-03 22:02:49.868 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[0] = 2
2013-03-03 22:02:49.870 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)2
2013-03-03 22:02:49.875 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[2] = (int64)8
2013-03-03 22:02:49.878 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: details: SQLite bind[3] = (int64)1
2013-03-03 22:02:49.880 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: COMMIT
2013-03-03 22:02:49.909 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: pragma page_count
2013-03-03 22:02:49.911 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0026s
2013-03-03 22:02:49.913 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: sql: pragma freelist_count
2013-03-03 22:02:49.915 Clueless[1168:907] CoreData: annotation: sql execution time: 0.0021s
```

This is really puzzling me as no errors are produced on loading or adding data to the data stores, so it should in theory work.

Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Well, the obvious question is, are you sure you're listening for the notification? And not somehow unregistering for it?

Comment: Yeah, there is no unregistering - the observer is on the app delegate along with all of the other core data stuff. The receipt.0.cdt files are both only 1kb, so I wonder if anything is moving into the cloud in the first place

Answer (score 1):

For people still trying to figure out why they are not receiving this notification: Provide the name of the notification as a constant rather than as a string(code in Swift).

Don't do:

```
"NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification"
```

Instead, do:

```
NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your database store is getting created for iCloud, but nothing is being put into it.

The receipt.0.cdt file appears in the transaction log folder for each device using that app through iCloud, but only initially (on store creation, or connection to an existing store from another device).  The transaction logs that actually contain the data are named more like:

```
FFFE99DC-87D7-5CBE-BFD8-32E11-D3E934.1.cdt
```

and are of a size that is proportional to the number of records inserted/updated/deleted etc in that transaction. These transaction logs appear in the iCloud device folder related to the device that generated those transactions.

A device that has connected to iCloud for that app, but NOT performed any transactions of its own, will just have the receipt.0.cdt file in it.

If you unzip the receipt.0.cdt, you end up with a text file - and all this seems to contain is a reference to the device these transaction logs were generated against (though initially is empty).

```
mobile.DEVICE_ID:NUMBER_OF_TRANSACTIONS
```

And this then grows to show:

```
mobile.DEVICE_TWO:2:mobile.DEVICE_ONE:4
```

so receipt.0.cdt is just a housekeeping reference for the number of transactions recorded against each device connected to that store in iCloud.

Concentrate on making sure you're actually putting data into your **iCloud** store (using the correct context, aren't getting mixed up with the local store context etc), and then actually saving it.

If none of that works, try blowing away the entire iCloud container and starting again in case something has gone wrong inside your ubiquity store (the standard response to just about every Core Data iCloud conundrum!).

Comment: Any idea why the notification is fired only when I launch the app and not anymore after that, when I update the iCloud data in another device? I activated logging and I see the update arrives (lot of logging in the console, apparently no errors) but none of the notifications is fired and when I fetch data is not updated. It will be only updated after next app launch.